# Show subdomain content on main domain Using htaccess?

Tags: .htaccess, subdomain

If the user enters `www.example.com/blog`, I want him to see what's in `blog.example.com`.

Another example:

User will request `www.example.com/blog/example-post/`, he'll see what's in `blog.example.com/example-post`.

The same for anything happening on the subdomain `blog.example.com`, for example:
Search:

`blog.example.com/search?s=example` will be `example.com/blog/search?s=example`

Comment: Are you referring to an external "redirect"? ie. the URL in the browser will change to `blog.example.com/<whatever>`?

Comment: Thanks a lot for the reply @MrWhite . No I do not want a redirect, I want the contents of the subdomain to show in the domain.

Thanks again for your time.

Comment: Where does the subdomain point to on the filesystem in relation to the main domain? Or are they unrelated, pointing to different servers or something? If the subdomain and main domain are pointing to the same filesystem then the request can simply be internally rewritten. However, if the subdomain is pointing to a different server then you need to configure your main domain as a reverse proxy, which requires access to the server config.

Comment: Sorry for the delayed comment @MrWhite. 

The server is a shared hosting.
The domain points to a folder created via cpanel addondomains section.
There subdomain will point to another folder created via cpanel. Maybe blog.example.com pointing to a subfolder /blog in the same shared hosting cpanel.
I want example.com/blog to show the contents from blog.example.com .

Thank you very much for your time.

Comment: I'm still not sure of your file/domain structure? It sounds like `example.com/blog` and `blog.example.com` might already be pointing to the same directory? But I guess not if this isn't working. In cPanel you can configure exactly were addon domains and subdomains point to - so this is potentially solvable in cPanel alone. Otherwise, please edit your question to include the complete file structure, indicating where the main domain and subdomain point to.

Comment: I am very sorry for the confusing question from my side @MrWhite

I want to achieve the following. The site https://example.com would be a wordpress site with one layout.
But https://example.com/blog would be another wordpress with a different layout. For this I would be installing the wordpress at the subdomain blog.example.com.

I want to show the contents of blog.example.com when a user visits https://example.com/blog

Thanks a lot for your valuable time.

Comment: This sounds like a WordPress question, rather than `.htaccess` since `example.com/blog` and `blog.example.com/` already point to the same filesystem location? (They do, don't they?) You then need to _configure WordPress_ to serve the same site from two different hosts. But why do you need the `blog` subdomain at all? If you want the blog to display at `example.com/blog`, just install it at `example.com/blog`?

Comment: Thanks for your reply @mrwhite. I would like to use two different layouts, 
For the home page one layout
For the blog - another layout with another wordpress installation. For this I would like to install wordpress on subdomain, blog.example.com . I want the contents of this page to be shown when my user types example.com/blog

Thanks a lot

Comment: Is there any connection with the following question on StackOverflow - they seem to have done exactly what you are trying to do (although the question is asking about something else)? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64529490/htaccess-301-redirect-with-an-exception

Comment: Thanks again for your time @MrWhite . I followed the link you provided & tried the code 
`RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Host}
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(blog)\.example\.com$ [NC]  
RewriteRule (.*) https://example.com/%1/$1 [R=302,L]
`
But when i type https://blog.example.com , it gets redirected to https://example.com/blog , but i am only seeing a page not found error. I want the contents of https://blog.example.com to be shown on https://example.com/blog